# Fix race condition with independent AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, race-condition

In my Angular application I have a main view that changes according to the route, and then a sidebar that is displayed no matter what. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar" ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">(sidebar code)</div>
    <div ng-view id="content">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript is loaded in this order:

1. Vendor.js (angular, etc)
2. App.js (my application)

The SidebarCtrl is defined in App.js. However right when Angular loads it sees the `ng-controller` directive and tries to assign it to the sidebar right off the bat, leading to a "argument SidebarCtrl is not a function" error unless app.js is cached. I was thinking of having the sidebar in a separate file and loading it before Vendor.js, but the sidebar is dependent on some services defined in App.js (namely, my custom auth service):

```
MyApp.controller('SidebarCtrl', 
['$scope', '$location', 'auth', function($scope, $location, auth) {
    (...)
}])
```

So either way I'm at a loss.

I'm sure there is a better way of setting this up...any ideas? Can I define `SidebarCtrl` as a simple function but still have access to the `auth` service?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `angular.bootstrap` or `ng-app` to initialize your app?

Comment: I'm using ng-app - I've seen references to angular.bootstrap but not really sure what that does. If I take out ng-app can I use angular.bootstrap() to start the app on the <body> tag?

Comment: Yes, after your app loads, you can call `angular.bootstrap(angular.element('body'), [ 'myApp'])`.

Comment: Awesome, working perfectly. Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *dynamically* add the `ng-controller` attribute to the `sidebar` when your app loads:

```js
var $self = angular.element('.sidebar');
$self.attr('ng-controller', window.USER_LOGGED_IN ? 'sidebarCtrl' : 'noUserCtrl');
angular.bootstrap(angular.element('body'));
```

This method is useful when the controller to be used depends on the application state. In your case, `angular.bootstrap` should do the trick.

[Source](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap#comment-534277364)

Comment: What does running angular.bootstrap without defining modules do? Would the inlineEditorCtrl still have access to services defined in the MyApp module?

Comment: You should angular.element instead of jQuery. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: The important part here is that angular is loaded in the same context as the setting of the attribute. Hence, it'll look at the `inlineEditorCtrl` only after it has bootstrapped your complete app and, by then, the module will be defined. Hence, the controller will be fully functional by the time you load. In your case, you do not even need to set the controller dynamically and angular should see it only after it loads.